# Function 'calculateAverageCountryPopulation' should work for an empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AC14S.png)

```js
const populations = [42000000, 9500000, 3500000, 8400000];
```

How can i fix this?

```js
function calculateAverageCountryPopulation(populations) {
  const initialValue = 0;
  const sum =
    populations.reduce((a, b) => a + b, initialValue) / populations.length;
  return sum;
}

console.log(calculateAverageCountryPopulation(populations));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this !

```js
const populations = [42000000, 9500000, 3500000, 8400000];

function calculateAverageCountryPopulation(populations) {
  const initialValue = 0;
  return populations.length>0 ? populations.reduce((a, b) => a + b, initialValue) / populations.length:0
};

console.log(calculateAverageCountryPopulation(populations));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply check if the array contains any elements

```js
function calculateAverageCountryPopulation(populations) {
  if (!populations.length) {
    return 0;
  }

  const sum = populations.reduce((total, population) => total + population, 0);
  const average = sum / populations.length;

  return average;
}
```